# Please explain a line of code shown below

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, method-chaining

This code is not my own. Credit: [Java Swing – JFileChooser example](https://mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-jfilechooser-example/)

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(
    FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
```

Please explain this line of code. I get that it's method chaining, but `FileSystem` is on object correct?

So, the `JFileChooser` object is taking the `FileSystemView` object with the two chained methods as it's arguments?

Is the `getFileSystemView()` method calling the `getHomeDirectory()` method?

**`FileChooser1`**

```
package com.mkyong.jfileChooser;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class FileChooser1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(
            FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());//<--p

        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ``FileSystemView.getFileSystemView() `` is a static factory method that returns the FileSystemView object. ``FileSystemView.getHomeDirectory()`` returns a File that points to the user's home directory.

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Also look at the preview of the post below the posting / editing area. Make sure it formats as you expect,

Answer (score 1):

The JFileChooser class has multiple types of constructors defined(Constructor Overloading).
One of the constructor method is JFileChooser(File) which takes a File object value as the argument.

In your code,the JFileChooser instance is being created with a File object instance represnting the  homedirectory  as the parameter.

The FileSystemView is a class with getFileSystemView static method to return an instance of the FileSystemView(Hence called a factory method,analogous to a factory which produces some product).
The FileSystemView type object has a method in it called getHomeDirectory() which will return the a File object which is an abstraction of the homedirectory.
To summarize the below line of code:

```
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(
        FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
```

you are instantiating an instance of JFileChooser using the constructor type JFileChooser(File) and rather than passing a File value explicitly you are invoking the FileSystemView method to return the value which will be passed as an argument to the JFileChooser constructor.

The same code can be written as below

```
    FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File file = fileSystemView.getHomeDirectory();
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(file);//<--p
```